# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse at graph.user.ts:198:19 mgt-people picker

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am using Mgt-people-picker and there is a very intermittent issue.
There is a need to pre-populate users by passing the email address some can be users from same azure tenant and some can be any external email addresses.
When passing array of email address to the people picker the below error comes up

````
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at graph.user.ts:198:19
    at u (runtime.js:63:40)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:294:22)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:119:21)
    at i (16.5f455671.chunk.js:2:615193)```
````

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Could you please provide any repro steps or sample code referred?

Comment: This is the how I am using the mgt people picker

<PeoplePicker
                                id="chat_recipients"
                                type={PersonType.person}
                                selectionChanged={onChangePeople}
                                userType={UserType.user}
                                defaultSelectedUserIds={defaultSelectedUsers}
                              />


The defaultSelectedUsers is an array of email address strings

Comment: This is a very intermittent issue when we invoke our app in Teams, it does not populate any users in people picker even if the user is in the same tenant or any external email addres
It gives error in the browser console I have mentioned in the original post

Comment: Could you please provide more details on the error? It's not much clear. Console error what you are getting? Any SS of the error?

Comment: This is the complete error message from browser

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at graph.user.ts:198:19
at u (runtime.js:63:40)
at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:294:22)
at Generator.next (runtime.js:119:21)
at i (16.08960254.chunk.js:2:610344)

Comment: I am just passing an array of user email as to the defaultSelectedUserIds

Comment: Could you please try once with AAD Object Id (UserId) instead of email adress?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/people-picker#properties

Comment: Adding the userID is not giving any issue, however we were passing the email address for past few weeks which worked. Were there any major changes to this component that is stopping us from passing email address?

Comment: Not sure about that. There might be some changes at SDK side

Comment: What would you suggest on this? Passing the UserIDs instead

Comment: Yes that will be better way

Comment: I can try that, but this is very intermittent. Sometimes it works with email address too. not sure if this will work for sure with userIds